# get content sent with cfhttp post

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp

I have a cfc that makes a call to a remote service using cfhttp.  The service is returning a failure code, which means that my call to the remote service is not formatted properly.  Is there any way to capture the content of a cfhttp post I'm sending?  I want to capture the raw post data so I can see where my formatting problem is. Here is a sample of what my code looks like:

```
<cfhttp url="https://www.webservice.com" method="POST" result="httpResponse">
  <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="method" value="doSomething">
  <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="user" value="myUserName">
  <cfhttpparam type="formField" name="password" value="myPassword">
</cfhttp>
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
<cfset result = structNew() />
<cfset result["response"] = httpResponse />
<cfset result["sentContent"] = cfhttp.sentContent />
```

Is it possible to get the content of a sent cfhttp without looking at the server logs.  My server is offsite and getting the logs will be a PITA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a template to which you would POST to. That template could return the result of [GetHttpRequestData()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_e-g_43.html) function.

Comment: I was hoping to get the post content during the same process as making the call to the remote service I'm using, but if that's not possible, I'll see if I can make this work.

Comment: If you're working on a local server or have access to the server you can always try using something like this http://www.charlesproxy.com/